# Split linked list shows empty outside the function scope

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have a C program which splits a linked list. The logic is this - If the linked list has even number of nodes, split it into equal halves. Else split it with the the parent linked list having one node more than the child linked list.
When I run the below code, the display_LL function in the main loop prints the 'p' linked list correctly.i.e. its split correctly. But the display_LL function prints the 'r' linked list NULL.

Whereas when I am printing the linked lists from inside the 'frontbacksplit_LL' function, 'p' and 'r' linked lists are displayed correctly.

Why this different behavior, I cannot understand.

Is this a scoping problem? If so, what changes do I need to make in the code?

Pls assume linked list 'p' is not an empty linked list. It has nodes. I just omitted the code for clarity. Also the display_LL function code is also not shown.

```
struct node {
    int data;
struct node *link;
};

void main()
{
    struct node *p,*q,*r;

    p=NULL;
    q=NULL;
    frontbacksplit_LL(p,r,count(p));   //Imagine p has nodes. count(p) gives number of 
    printf("Front_Back Splits:\n");    //nodes in the linked list.
    display_LL(p);   //displays split linked list correctly
    display_LL(r);   //Shows EMPTY linked list.
    getch();
}

frontbacksplit_LL(struct node *a,struct node *b,int node_count)
{
    struct node *temp;
    int i,t;
    temp=a;

    if(node_count%2==0) //even
    {
        for(i=0;i<node_count/2;i++)
            temp=temp->link;
        b=temp->link;
        temp->link=NULL;
    }
    else
    {

        for(i=0;i<(ceil(node_count/2));i++)
            temp=temp->link;
        b=temp->link;
        temp->link=NULL;
    }
    display_LL(a); //Displays split linked list correctly.
    display_LL(b); //Displays split linked list correctly.
}
```

Comment: Modifying pointers passed as arguments: http://agnelkurian.com/blog/?p=168

Comment: THANKS everybody for your help. All your suggestions are equally valid. But I found that a small tweak to the code made it work. What I did was send the reference to r like this: frontbacksplit_LL(struct node *a,struct node **b,int node_count)

and call it like this: frontbacksplit_LL(p,&r,count(p));

to the function and voila it worked! No need to send the reference of parent linked list (thats what I have observed).

Any comments on this?

Comment: You are not changing the parent list pointer. So, no need to pass it by reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the pointer variables `p` and `r` are passed by value to the function `frontbacksplit_LL`. As a result any changes made inside function `frontbacksplit_LL` are local to the function ( as you are changing the copies).

Since you want the changes made to variables `a` and `b` in function `frontbacksplit_LL` get reflected in variables `p` and `q` in `main`, you need to pass `p` and `q` by address as:

```
frontbacksplit_LL(struct node **a, struct node **b, int node_count) {
```

and then access the actual pointers through `*a` and `*b`. That is in your existing code replace `a` with `*a` and `b` with `*b`.

and call it as:

```
frontbacksplit_LL(&p, &r, count(p));
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you pass pointers `p` and `q` by value. So when you change them inside `frontbacksplit_LL` these changes aren't visible outside the function. You should pass the pointers by pointers rather by value, like

```
frontbacksplit_LL(struct node **a,struct node **b,int node_count)
```

Of course, you have to replace all `a` and `b` in the function code with `*a` and `*b`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
struct node *p,*q,*r;
frontbacksplit_LL(p, r, count(p));
```

In order to do it right, you need to declare `r` as a pointer to pointer to the second half. In your code `r` is passed by value, so the result is stored in the local variable `b` of `frontbacksplit_LL`. If you pass the address of `r` (i.e. `&r`) it would be done correctly.

The function declaration should be:

```
frontbacksplit_LL(struct node** a, struct node** b, int node_count)
```

and all the `a`s and `b`s should be replaced with `*a` and `*b` respectively. Then you should call it as

```
struct node *p = NULL, *q = NULL, *r;
frontbacksplit_LL(&p, &r, count(p));
```

or

```
struct node **p = NULL, *q = NULL, **r;
frontbacksplit_LL(p, r, count(p));
```

In this case you'd need to access the lists through `*p` and `*r`.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct llist {
        struct llist *next;
        char *payload;
        };

struct llist *llist_split(struct llist **hnd );

struct llist *llist_split(struct llist **hnd)
{
struct llist *this, *save, **tail;
unsigned iter=0;

for (save=NULL, tail = &save; this = *hnd; ) {
        if ( !this->next) break;
        if ( ++iter & 1 ) { hnd = &this->next; continue; }
        *tail = this;
        *hnd = this->next;
        tail = &(*tail)->next;
        *tail = NULL;
        }
return save;
}
```

BTW: main() should return int.